# Webbased backup tools for linux

Tags: backup, remote-backup

Is there any simple  backup tools for linux which can be operated remotely via web i.e is there any offline backup tool with web based gui?

Answer (score 1):

https://bitcalm.com - is what your are looking for.

- Remote web-based dashboard to configure and manage your backups for
  single or even multiple Linux machines
- Daily incremental backups for files and/or databases
- Single click restore feature
- you can either use their Amazon s3 storage or provide credentials for your cloud storage to save the backups.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. It's called Idera backup, you have 2 options - free and paid. You can check mini review [at this link](http://www.itsmdaily.com/2013/09/10/idera-server-backup-free/). It's UI is browser based and it supports Linux as well. Do you have any special requirements for backup other than accessible via browser?